# LinuxOS для Ruby, Node-npm, webpack и react

Tags: linux

Какую сборку Linux устанавливать?

Цель: разработка react приложений с использованием ruby, node, npm, sass и webpack. С windows постоянно какие то проблемы с установкой пакетов. Порекомендуйте, пожалуйста, какая сборка Linux больше подходит под эти задачи.

Ubuntu ставить не хочется. Хорошие отзывы о  Arch Linux и Debian. На чем лучше остановиться, а может, есть лучшие и более современные альтернативы?

Comment: А чем убунта не устроила?

Comment: Любой. Существенных причин выбрать тот или иной первым дистром нет. К убунте больше инструкций разве что, но многие из них актуальны и для Debian. Сам использую Linux Mint Debian Edition.

Comment: Неважно какой. Для меня главное, чтобы был удобен. В последние года два использовал kubuntu, до этого SuSE. Дома под новый Год поставил Mint 17.3 Mate

Comment: @D-side, большое спасибо за совет, прочитала описание к дистрибутиву на оф. сайте. Написано, что там меньше фичей, чем у Linux Mint, но зато он поддерживает самые последние пакеты. Это то, что нужно!

Comment: @Hermann Zheboldov, благодарю за совет,   хороший дистрибутив, user-friendly interface, хорошая совместимость с другими программами и поддержка до 2019года! В общем, буду определяться между этими двумя дистрибутивами.

Comment: @OlgaMoscow там же сказано, что "targeted at experienced users" (нацелен на опытных пользователей). А последние пакеты обычно есть в PPA, когда они очень нужны. Что касается NodeJS и Ruby, то их всё равно обычно лучше ставить в userspace из менеджера версий (а не из репозиториев), что делает выбор дистрибутива ещё менее осмысленным процессом :)

Comment: @D-side, спасибо, тогда и вопросов нет!:) Мне главное, чтобы не было проблем с установкой node модулей и плагинов к webpack. Но похоже, система гибкая, на ней, пожалуй, и остановлюсь.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ruby** и **NodeJS** для разработчика частенько необходимы не одной версии. В идеале — той же, что работает/будет работать в продакшене. Поэтому установка оных из системных репозиториев на машине разработчика — вариант сомнительный, версия вряд ли совпадёт.

Есть менеджеры версий **[RVM](https://rvm.io/)** (для Ruby) и **[N](https://github.com/tj/n)** (для NodeJS). Они стараются устанавливать все необходимые зависимости для самих интерпретаторов самостоятельно и умеют держать на одной машине несколько версий интерпретатора сразу практически без конфликтов (*практически* значит "я не сталкивался"), быстро переключяясь между ними.

**Вас устроит любой дистрибутив, на котором работают они или их аналоги.**

Comment: За подсказку про менеджеры большое спасибо! Жаль, что раньше не спросила, это многие вопросы с сайтом бы решило)) Поставлю LMDE, там уже буду по ходу разбираться.

Answer (score 0):

логичнее всего использовать ту сборку программы *linux*, которая присутствует в репозитории выбранного вами дистрибутива операционной системы *gnu/linux*.

если же у вас трудности с выбором **дистрибутива** (ubuntu, debian, arch или ещё какой-нибудь из сотен (или уже тысяч?) существующих), то наилучший слышанный мною совет по этому поводу — ставьте тот дистрибутив, что использует ближайший к вам «гуру».

Comment: согласна, проще всего ориентироваться на знакомого "гуру", но он на MacOS.))

Comment: @OlgaMoscow, для того, чтобы ваши комментарии дошли до `don Rumata` и `D-side`, их надо оставлять именно под тем сообщением (вопросом либо ответом), где они писали свои комментарии. под моим ответом они комментариев не писали. они их писали под вашим вопросом. вот под вопросом и нажимайте кнопку «добавить комментарий».

Comment: большое спасибо, что поправили, сейчас исправлю!)

Comment: я получила однозначно правильный ответ, который одобрила.  Не вижу объективных причин для удаления своего вопроса. Этот комментарий адресован ко всем модераторам. Если есть другой вариант правильного написания этого комментария, пожалуйста, сообщите мне об этом.

Comment: @OlgaMoscow, подобные вопросы можно обсудить в [чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22462).