# Разница между 4 и 5 версией NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

На данный момент я использую NodeJS четвёртой ветки, в основном для gulp/grunt/bower, а также изучаю технологию. Жутко привлекает пятая версия, но страшно её ставить.

Поясните, в двух словах, в чём основная разница веток и можно ли уже "по полной" использовать пятерку, не вспоминая о четвёртой версии?

Comment: Возможно, [проще поставить менеджер версий](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/482739/181100) и не задаваться такими вопросами вообще, сразу пробовать. Не прокатило -- переключился и забыл.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

4 версия объявлена как LTS(Long Term Support) переводится как Длинный Срок Поддержи. Если вы не ставите Node.js на рабочем сервере, то можете спокойно ставить 5 версию. 4 версия скорее для корпоративного сегмента, где важнее стабильность и надежность, вместо погони за новыми версиями.

Если интересны изменения, внесенные после версии 4.4, можете посмотреть [changelog](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/v5.8.0/CHANGELOG.md)

Comment: Спасибо за ссылку. А я думал что 4 не поддерживает например ES6, с логом всё станет понятнее. :)